# Abstraction for distributed CancellationToken

Tags: c#, .net, cloud, distributed-computing, cancellation

Talking about cancellation and microservices/cloud architecture, it seems that standard .NET `CancellationTokenSource` class does not fit the needs: it does not provide any extensibility mechanism, allowing to store state in external centralized storage and making it possible to cancel operation, which started executing on one service instance from another service instance.

For **example**, I might have service "Customer" with costly "UploadAvatar" method (in reality I have method executing for few minutes). Service "Customer" is scaleable and we have 2 instances of it. User uploads his photo and we start processing it. At this point he uploads another photo, and old job is no longer actual, so for performance reasons we need to cancel it.

Searching over the internet didn't give me any obvious implementations to this basic task. Does anyone know library which provide distributed operation cancellation? And do you have any thoughts why .NET FCL does not provide such class or abstraction?

**PS:** It would be nice if abstraction is as close as possible to existing `CancellationToken` public interface, so that it it easier to migrate existing code into cloud and scale existing services.

Comment: `CancellationTokenSource` is merely an object that is used for TPL-related stuff in fairly simple scenarios. Your scenario is much more sophisticated. In order to achieve these requirements you could use a message broker such as RabbitMQ or MassTransit and create a command for stopping the services that will be handled by `Customer` service asynchronously. I'd advise to read more about MicroServices architecture specifically the part that's explaining how different services talk to each other. AFAIK there are no library developed for this specifically.